# how to group timestamp in a week of 7 days?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I am receiving data as a stat_timestamp and an end_timestamp
like

```
end_ts: 1605205800
start_ts:1602700200
```

when I convert them to get full day they are as follows:

```
start_ts:15-10-2020
end_ts:14-11-2020
```

I want to group the data in 7 days period to include start_ts and end_ts as follows:

```
15 Oct - 21 Oct,
22 oct to 28Oct, 
29 oct to 04 Nov, 
05 oct to 11 Nov 
12 oct to 18 Nov
```

Any idea how I can implement the above behavior? am quite stuck with the process. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a loop in which you add 6 days to the start date, print it, and add one more day to it (this gives you Oct 15th and Oct 21st). The next iteration of the loop would do the same but start out with Oct 22nd (one day was added). You keep doing that until the last day you're printing (Nov 18th) is greater or equal to the end timestamp (Nov 14th). A date library like https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs would greatly help.